# Workflow iOS app / Custom navigation + tab bar controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

This is my very very first post ever on this
amazing community. Been browsing it for quite a while now and
I'm totally in love with it.

I've been learning iOS for a few weeks now and still struggling
about the best way to achieve a robust and solid structure for
the application I'm building. I figured out the "**UITabBarController**"
was the best way to achieve my goal, but still, I wanted the tab-bar
to go away and make my own 'extreme' custom navigation. The custom
navigation would be a **UIViewController** with a view, and the view containing
`UIButtons`.

So this appears in my **AppDelegate.m**:

```
// ASSIGN CUSTOM NAV & TAB BAR CONTROLLER 
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[tabBarController.view addSubview:customNavController.view];
```

And I have this in my **AppDelegate.h**:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomNavigationViewController* customNavController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController* tabBarController;
```

Is this the right way to do it? So I can always go to my `AppDelegate`
and have my `customNavController` available to send messages to..
And my `tabBarController` as well, to set the `selectedIndex` property for example.

So the main question remains:
I have a `UITabBarController` (holding all the sections of the app) and a `UIViewController` (custom navigation) and I'd like them to be able to **talk to eachother**.

UPDATE: Here's a screenshot of the scheme how I see the flow in my head:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5k49pe2idn6zxcd/ios_customnavigation_scheme.png

Any tricks / tips are welcome! Curious what you guys come up with.
Thanks in advance, 
Y.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you intend to use these controllers in your app or why you need them to talk to one another but you can embed UINavigationControllers in each of the 'tabs' of the UITabBarController.  You can also hide the Tab bar in your customer views if necessary (plenty of questions/answers on this if you search the site).  These built in controllers will then handle view changes without you having to deal with the details and is of course much easier then rolling your own.

If you haven't i would review the Apple documentation on MVC as it might help you make some of your design decisions.

Best of luck.

Comment: Bejan, thanks for the answer but it's not really what I was aiming for. I'd like to have "one" instance of navigation visible through all the different sections (or tabs) from the UITabBarController. So it should sit on top of the tab-controller. In your case, I shall have a new navigation instance for each section, no? Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: That's correct, i was not quite understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: So do you have any other suggestions of having my CustomNavigation only built once and have it always on top of the TabBarController? I updated my post and included a link to a Screenshot. Have a look!

Comment: I think i understand what you are trying to do and it doesn't sound like a UITabBarController is what you want.  The tab controller will switch what's in the main view by pushing another view associated with a view controller (one for each tab).  What it seems you want is a way to switch what a portion of the screen will display when a user hits a button (bottom of your screen in the drawing).  It seems to me that this could be done with a single view controller that presents multiple views that are properly sized and positioned on screen.

Comment: But is that a clean solution to mix all sections (views) into one UIViewController and have the views positioned properly on the screen when the user clicks a button? Because I'm going to have a built-in Apple's map in one of the sections, is that even possible to have such a "Map" in a view? Thanks for your point of view so far! It's helping me out with some bits.

Comment: to be more accurate and add to what i said, your view controller can only have a single UIView in its view property. That view though can certainly be used to contain other subviews.  I'm not sure if it's the best solution for your application but this is certainly viable.

Comment: Interesting.. I'm still hesitating between UIViews and UIViewControllers.. For example, if I have all the views in ONE UIViewController, even though I only need to show one view (section) at a time, how is that going to affect the memory? TabBarController releases the old view/viewcontroller when a new one comes in, right?

Comment: I'm confused again, lol, if you are only showing one view at a time and the 3 views don't need to be displayed at the same time then i think simply using a UITabBarController is what you want.  Even though the controllers added to each 'tab' would be separate instantiations they could load and unload each time and present what you want independent of each other (based on your model).